# Cygwin /etc/passwd not honoring /bin/bash

Tags: windows-xp, bash, cygwin, etcpasswd

How can I get Cygwin to honor the /etc/passwd file and make my default shell bash instead of sh?

I presume it is controlled somehow by windows XP since I had an issue before with permissions and had to regenerate the /etc/passwd file after updating permissions on Win XP for my user id.

Comment: How are you invoking the shell? Also, check that the SHELL variable which would override the /etc/passwd setting, isn't set.

Comment: The `SHELL=/bin/bash` and it is invoked by emacs via `meta-x shell` running inside by x window system started by `startx`

Comment: Right. How do you know that you are running /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash?

Comment: Because the prompt is `sh-4.1$' and if I execute `bash` I get a new prompt of `[xp-pro-sp3 ~] ??? `

Comment: Fair enough. Are you sure your `/etc/passwd` entry is correct? You can use `mkpasswd -c` to print an appropriate entry for the current user. Another thing to try is to invoke one of the Cygwin terminals like `mintty` or `rxvt`, which invoke your default shell unless told otherwise. If you get bash there, this becomes an emacs issue.

Comment: I regenerated with `mkpasswd -c` which resulted in a slightly different entry but same results of sh instead of bash. I also confirmed that `mintty` comes up in sh instead of bash too.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Probably best to report this to the Cygwin mailing list with the cygcheck details requested at http://cygwin.com/problems.html.

Small differences in the SID field (S-1-5-21-...) can be crucial, but I presume you've replaced the entry in question now. Can you actually read `/etc/passwd` as the user that you're trying to run your shell as, i.e. what permissions does `ls -l` show for it?

Comment: Have not tried recently, but last I tried, it was still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this code in your `~/.emacs` startup file (and restarting Emacs):

```
(setq shell-file-name "bash"
      explicit-shell-file-name "bash")
```

You could also temporarilly rename `/bin/sh` to `/bin/sh.hold` to be absolutely certain whether Emacs is invoking `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.  Keep in mind that in certain cases (see the Bash man page) Bash will behave as sh depending on how it is invoked (e.g., if `argv[0]` is "sh").